# Xfce dark theme font colours

Tags: software-center, themes, fonts, xfce, youtube

I have a problem with dark theme. I'm using Ubuntu Studio and Nox theme. Unfortunately I cannot see youtube like/dislike ratio because its font with this theme is almost white. This problem rarely concerns option bars on other sites. Also in software center after selecting a program, font is unreadable because of white selection background and white font. Can I change colour of these fonts? Or maybe you could recommend me some other dark theme that would be good for my eyes – not too dark and with low contrast – and without any issues making some program unreadable because of its unsuitable colours?

Comment: Don't forget to inform the developer of the Nox theme of your difficulties. Another point is to choose a theme that is regularly updated and not old. I couldn't find any recent links to the Nox theme. Where did you get it from? Also, ensure that the theme supports both gtk2 and gtk3.

Comment: Nox theme is pre-installed on Ubuntu Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xubuntu, open Theme Configuration. If you have only installed Xfce from another desktop environment, then you can paste `sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config` in terminal to install. Launch the application and change the top category *Custom highlight colors* to your preferred colors. Log out and log in again. This should fix the issue on Ubuntu Software Center.

To fix the YouTube Like/Dislike text, go to the `gtkrc` file you downloaded with this theme. I installed for my testing by going [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/ECSTATiCA%20(formerly%20NOX)?content=105349). Then I named the file .gtkrc-2.0 and placed it in my home directory for it to be activated on my system. However, you may have the file in another location. Open this file. Go to the line that starts with `gtk_color_scheme` (line 60 in my file). Change this `fg_color: #EEEEEC` to this `fg_color: #686A6A` or whichever darker color you prefer. This color matches the hexadecimal number for the little thumbs up/down icons on YouTube. You may need to log out and in again for changes to take effect. However, this was not necessary for me. I only needed to restart Firefox.

If things are still not optimal after these changes, I fully understand where you're coming from on this. I always want my themes to be 100% perfect to my liking. It is great that with enough knowledge and persistence you can make things just as you like. You may want to try out a few other of these themes if you haven't done so already. [Numix Dark Theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454372/dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu-14-04) is probably pretty nice. I've also seen [Spatry talk about some cool themes](https://youtu.be/R-90T9EsbmI). If you dig into the config files after installing a full theme, then with enough persistence you can usually figure out how to change little aspects. My previous [post here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606132/xfce-themes-customization/656265#656265) may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks again jbrock :), gtk-theme-config helped with Ubuntu Software Center. Unfortunetely I still don't have any idea how to solve the problem with youtube like/dislike ratio font colour. I have noticed that this issue is not related to Google Chrome. It appears only in Firefox.

Comment: @user468193 I've updated my answer above to fix the Firefox issue. I hope all works out great.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I have followed your instructions. Unfortunately changing this parameter affects also font colour for xfce panel and menus. So when I change this colour to darker I can see youtube like/dislike ratio, but I cannot see text of menus and panel because of dark font on dark background. I could change colour of this font to black, but then I would have to change transparency of desktop panel(which is now fully transparent on black desktop wallpaper). I had to make it transparent because without it panel tray icons had in Nox theme white background(sic!)

Comment: It is quite frustrating. On one hand looking for perfect dark theme or configuring existing one seams to be pointless and a waste of time because of small but irritating flaws. And on the other I know that it is probably quite simple to make them work properly.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the Custom panel colors and Custom menu colors in Theme Configuration (gtk-theme-config)?

Comment: The category "Panel background" in Theme Configuration could be a little misleading. This is the background of buttons and other items when they're selected.

Comment: I've experimented a little with theme-config and colours of fg_colour. I've managed to make a compromise setting fg_colour to colour that is barely visible (but not invisible like before) in youtube like\dislike font and quite visible in menus. With theme-config (custom menu colours) I've limited the number of fonts witch are defined by fg_colour parameter to a few (menu bars font, font in end session window). I've been forced to turn off custom panel colours in theme-config because it affected colour of notification background and work space indicator background making it useless.

Comment: @user468193 I've updated my answer above with a little more content. I hope it can be of some help.

Comment: You've helped me a lot. I'm quite happy with the current look of Nox theme that I've managed to achieved with your help. Thanks again :)

Comment: I have one more question. Is there any simple way to change tooltips background transparency?

Comment: It can be changed by going to Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > Opacity of popup windows